# Loading file with HTML agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a list of websites that's been generated and stored into a text file. Now I'm trying to load that file so I can repeat the process of extracting website URLS. 
Every time I run that application, HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument is the only thing that's populated in the console window.

```
    private static async void GetHtmlAsync1()
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FilenameHere);
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }
```

Am I coming across this right?

Thanks

Comment: Doc is an object.  You have to extract values. What are you interested in getting from the doc

Comment: We all hope for good news from the doc... I was doing some research on the subject and ran across a getting started post and this was mentioned to read from a file, unless i misinterpreted it.                                                                                                         
 // From File
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);                                                                                                          All im trying to do is digg down a few layers in a website, if thats what you're asking

Comment: Please have a read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=netframework-4.8). Once you have the `HtmlDocument doc`, you will need to go through each of the nodes to get what you need. (`DocumentNode`, `Descendants`, `SelectNodes`, and `XPath` are the things you need to look up the definitions of.). Also, [see this for some examples as well](https://html-agility-pack.net/parser)

Comment: Rock on, I'm checking it out now. So what you're saying, in short, is that I can read a file of websites, store them in an arrays, then read them boy their index value?

Comment: if your test.txt has URLs, then you can Read the file and Go over each URL (retrieve data from that URL) and scan through it. yes.

Comment: Yea that's all the file consist of is URLs. And i was trying to use the Load(file name), as mentioned above, and it wasnt working and I was wondering if I was approaching it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of loading text file full or URLs and reading their content. My test file is in the same location as my project files.

```
    List<string> allUrls = File.ReadAllLines($@"{Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName}\test.txt").ToList();
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    foreach(string url in allUrls)
    {
        doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
        Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
    }
```

Please note, i am only printing the entire website, you can use HtmlAgilityPack to actually scrape the data you are interested in (like pulling all the links, or specific class item.

- Read in the lines from File
- Load the data from URL using HtmlWeb.
- Iterate through each URL and get what you need.

Comment: ohhhhhh okay, I see. I'm gonna mess around with that and see where it gets me.Thank you

Comment: @weeDoubleWide please mark the post as answered if it helped